# Count Distinct Combinations in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way in SQL to Count the number of occurences of a distict combination of two fields in a table e.g.

```
categorynum     itemnum
1               3
2               1
1               3 
1               2
3               1
1               3
```

and return 3 when counting occurences of (1;3) ?

Comment: What are the desired results? You want the count of rows for just `1;3` or all combinations?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just use a regular `GROUP BY` / `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT categorynum, itemnum, COUNT(*) occurrences
FROM {table}
GROUP BY categorynum, itemnum
```

If you want a particular combination just add a `WHERE` clause (before the `GROUP BY`):

```
WHERE categorynum = 1 AND itemnum = 3
```